# Get email with the diff changes from the last 'git pull'

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to get an email that will display the last changes made by git. It should be nicely formatted similar to github ( + are green, - are red).

This is what I have done so far:

1. Configured Jenkins to check every 5 minutes for changes, pull the changes, and send email.
2. Installed 'Jenkins Email Extension Plugin', configured it to work with a custom 'jelly' template, which send also the console output to the email.
3. I added a script to the build, which run 'git show'.

This way, I get the output of 'git show' to the email every 5 minutes if code is changed within this time.

What is missing is as follows:

1. If two commits occurred within 5 minutes, it'll show only the diff made by the last one. I guess that's what git show does. I need all the changes from the current code, not all changes from last commit.
2. It is not formatted nicely. it is just a plain text.

I'd appreciate any help here. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at using a post-receive hook instead of polling your repo? This would ensure that the job builds for each commit.

Comment: Not sure how it could work each commit, since commit is locally, and I guess that not every developer has a mail server on his machine. Besides, it'll not be formatted I guess. I don't use Jenkins only for this, I will use it later on also for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff --color @{yesterday}` (or whenever the last pull was done/differences are of interest) works nicely for me...

Comment: Cool! 'diff' not exactly helps me, but 'whatchanged' command can work with the last 5 minutes. So I ended up using this:   git whatchanged --since="5 minutes ago" -p --color. On the console it looks good. The problem is that in the email it'll take only the text not the colors. So I guess I'll have to insert some css to the jelly file